# readinf adc value on nucleo l476rg infiniteu loop problem

Tags: c, stm32, nucleo

I have this problem when trying to read the ADC value (using adc1_in6) on the nucleo-l476rg micro controlle: I get in an infinite loop when checking if the EOC bit of the status register (ISR) "adc_read function".

Here's the adc.c file content:

```
#include "stm32l476xx.h"
#include "adc.h"
#define ADC1_SEQL1 0X00
void pa1_adc1_init(void)
{
    /**************configure adc gpio pin ******************/
    //enable clock access to GPIOA
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= (1U<<0);
    //set the mode of pa1 to analog  mode
    GPIOA->MODER |=(1U<<2);
    GPIOA->MODER |=(1U<<3);
    /****************configure adc periph ******************/
    // enable clock access to adc module
    RCC->AHB2ENR |=(1U<<13);
    /*******configure adc parameters****************/
    //conversion sequence start
    ADC1->SQR1 |=(1U<<7);
    ADC1->SQR1 |=(1U<<8);
    //conversion sequence length
    ADC1->SQR1 &= 0xFFFFFFF0UL;
    //Enable adc module
    // Check voltage regulator status
    ADC1->CR &= 0x00000000;
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN;

    while (!(ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADVREGEN)) {
        // Wait for voltage regulator startup time to pass
    }

    // Set ADVREGEN bit to 1
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN;

    // Wait for voltage regulator startup time to pass

    // Set ADEN bit to 1
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
}

void start_conversion(void)
{
    /*start adc conversion   */
    ADC1->CR |=ADC_CR_ADSTART;


}

uint32_t adc_read(void)
{


    // wait for conversion to be complete
    while (!(ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)){}
    //read converted result from ADC1 data register
    return (ADC1->DR);
}
```

I reviewed the reference manual to check if there are any specific requirements about the ISR register but it doesn't show anything special to do.

Comment: After setting `ADVREGEN` to 1 software must wait "ADC voltage regulator start-up time" - 20uS. I don't see in the manual any notes, that this delay can be implemented by polling `ADVREGEN` bit.

Comment: There is also a specific ADC enable sequence, software must wait for `ADRDY` bit before starting the conversions. See "18.4.9 ADC on-off control" of the refence manual.

Comment: @Flexz it seemed that the problem was with the adc clock , i supplied the adc with the system clock  and the conversion started but its giving random numbers even when i connect a jumper wire between the pa1 pin and the gnd  i still don't know what's the problem...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to have delay (or readback as access is strongly ordered) when enable the clock as the next register access is very likely to fail.
2. ADC has more than one clock domain and enabling digital part is not enough
3. You should calibrate the ADC before use.

Comment: how long should the delay be ( I'll be doing it with an empty for loop) and where exactly should i add it ?

Comment: read reference manual